# how to understand calling compare_exchange_strong with std::memory_order_acquire

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

**Quoted from C++ Concurrency in Action 7.2.5-Applying the memory model to the lock-free stack.**

These following code is quoted from the book. And I know it is fine when there is only one pop thread. But if there are two threads pop, without the rule about the release sequence, could it be safe to use `memory_order_acquire`.

As far as I concerned, I need to replace memory_order_acquire with `memory_order_acq_rel`, which would introduce synchronization between the two pop thread. But the book says `memory_order_acquire` is enough.

Is my understanding of memory_order_acquire wrong: **acquire and release do not need to be paired**?

```
template<typename T>
class lock_free_stack
{
    void increase_head_count(counted_node_ptr& old_counter)
    {
        counted_node_ptr new_counter;
        do
        {
            new_counter=old_counter;
            ++new_counter.external_count;
        }

        // problem here
        while(!head.compare_exchange_strong(old_counter,new_counter
            ,std::memory_order_acquire,std::memory_order_relaxed));

        old_counter.external_count=new_counter.external_count;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
    {
        counted_node_ptr old_head=head.load();
        for(;;)
        {
            // call
            increase_head_count(old_head);

            node* const ptr=old_head.ptr;
            if(!ptr)
            {
                 return std::shared_ptr<T>();
            }
            if(head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,ptr->next))
            {
                 // todo delete
            }
            else if(ptr->internal_count.fetch_sub(1)==1)
            {
                delete ptr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `memory_order_acquire` is for use when you don't want any reads ordered prior to the atomic access. `memory_order_relaxed` should not currently be used because it currently basically removes all requirements. `memory_order_acq_rel` blocks reads from being reordered before the atomic read, and writes from being reordered after the write.

Comment: A [better explanation of the semantics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

Comment: Thanks for comment~ memory_order_acquire:1.no reads or writes in the [current thread] can be reordered before this load. 2.All writes in other threads that [release] the same atomic variable are visible in the current thread. Did not find a description of the synchronization between acquires. Is the author wrong?

Comment: That's because that's undefined, just the variable updates are guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: @Mgetz: `memory_order_relaxed` gives you atomicity but no ordering guarantees (other than being ordered by fences or other stronger operations before/after).  It's ridiculous to say it shouldn't be used.  It shouldn't be used *here*, but there are use-cases for `relaxed`, e.g. when you only have a single atomic variable that isn't a flag for other data being ready or anything like that.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm going off of conversations with committee members that said it has odd semantics in the standard right now and isn't well defined.

Comment: If the variable is only guaranteed to be atomic, then writes the variable in current thread may not visible in other thread. Isn't that impossible to avoid a data race?

Comment: @jiaping in theory the atomicity alone would prevent that, in practice atomicity is very rarely used alone. That's why the relaxed data order is so dangerous.

Comment: @Mgetz: well, in fact I was asking wether memory_order_acquire is enough here. And because memory_order_relaxed is used only when exchange failed, I think it is no problem here.

Comment: Use release when you want to inform other thread you have finished some tasks and they can rely on it when they see a particular value on some atomic object. The reading tasks have not finished or accomplished anything.